# mod_rewrite url with 2 params or more

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

URL: **`http://example.com/good_game/osmp/`**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(.*)$ /?service=$1&terminal=$2 [L,QSA]
```

i receive

```
Array ( [service] => good_game [terminal] => /osmp/ )
```

i need

```
Array ( [service] => good_game [terminal] => osmp )
```

and what RewriteRule i need for multiparams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give u what you want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?service=$1&terminal=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Your problem with your rule is that you're using `(.*)` after your first group so it will get anything left by that group which is `/anything/`.

So basically your rule is telling the server to get anything not a `/` so it gets good_game, then you're asking it to get anything left so it gets `/osmp/`.

Answer (score 1):

A RewriteRule like:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /?service=$1&terminal=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Should do what you need. Basically, put the characters you don't want in your parameters outside the () to avoid capturing them.